# Plugin adding extra elements every time plugin is initialized onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Carrousel is in a hidden div which gets initialized once the dropdown menu is clicked. Problem is it adds next and prev buttons every time the button is clicked as leaving me with multiple buttons. Is there away to initialize the plugin first time only?

```
$("#category").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$(".category-dropdown").toggle();

$("#category-slider").flexisel({
    visibleItems: 6,
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 6000,            
    pauseOnHover: true,
    enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
    responsiveBreakpoints: { 
        portrait: { 
            changePoint:480,
            visibleItems: 1
        }, 
        landscape: { 
            changePoint:640,
            visibleItems: 2
        },
        tablet: { 
            changePoint:768,
            visibleItems: 3
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The flexisel plugin do not support modification of object once initialized so it is not possible to do so right now through js.

You can create issue in the github repository and plugin author may add this feature.